Ngrx Pattern to set propery IsLoading while fetching new data from server
I have a store with actions, effects, reducers, and selectors. I have a component on the screen, and the component represents a store object, obtained via a selector.
What I'm trying to do is, I think, 2 things with 1 action. When a user updates the object, I want to dispatch an action to update the store object to set an isLoading property to true (which will re-emit to my component, which will respond to isLoading by blocking the UI). Meanwhile, I want an effect to save/refetch from the server. When the effect completes, it will dispatch the object back to the store with isLoading = false, which my UI would respond to by updating its fields and unblocking the UI.
How do I achieve both an effect and a reducer, and guarantee the order in which they return? Or is there a better pattern to use?


How do I achieve both an effect and a reducer, and guarantee the order in which they return? Or is there a better pattern to use?

Execution order is guaranteed: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/162 Effects will always execute after all reducers.
The flow you described is perfectly fine. I personally prefer a property status with possible values like 'loading' | 'loaded' | 'error' | ... but a simple boolean property isLoading is also okay.

Ok. So I need the reducer to at least resolve first, to set the status, even though it is extremely unlikely an effect's http call will return faster. Right now, in the component's onClick, I'm first dispatching the update (to reducer), then the save (to effect/server). It feels weird the the component, or even a regular service, needs to know what to do. Is it cool if the effect dispatches the update to reducer?

@emery.noel your code will look like this: dispatch an action updateMyObject -> reducer for action updateMyObject sets isLoading to true -> effect for action updateMyObject pushes data to your API (as I wrote before, effect will always execute after all reducers, so order is guaranteed) -> server returns a result and your effect immediately dispatches an action myObjectUpdated -> reducer for action myObjectUpdated sets isLoading to false. Do not create two separate actions for changing isLoading property and pushing data to API!

@emery.noel " Is it cool if the effect dispatches the update to reducer?" - it is absolutely okay to dispatch an action from an effect

thanks so much. Yeah I agree about the statuses vs boolean, this is just a test project for me to learn on. Now I'm struggling with, I have an array of objects and I want to update one property of one object, and I find myself having to spread practically the entire store. I do not like that pattern.

@emery.noel the pattern is okay, it is not the responsibility of a pattern to make array or object management easier. You either need a global store in your app or not. But if you want to have all possible helper methods for entity management, then check @ngrx/entity package.
